# How to stop rendering of a certain section of code by using js/ts exactly like what happen when we use *ngIf in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, render, angular-ng-if

We can comment or use css (display:none) to hide a certain part of the html code. But the code is actually available in the developers tools. How do we make use of the features of js or ts to stop rendering these part of the html like we make use of the *ngIf directive of angular?  To stop the rendering

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript method remove() It will remove the complete selected HTML dom from the HTML.

Refer following example:

```
<p id="elementId">This paragraph will be removed from the DOM.</p>

    var obj = document.getElementById("elementId");//elementId will be your html element id
    obj .remove();
```